# Rails undefined method `id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

Phonecall and Result:

```
class Phonecall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phonecall
end
```

All easy, if I do this code:

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @phonecalls = Phonecall.order('datetime DESC').all

  end

end
```

and in view:

```
<% @phonecalls.each do |ph| %>
  <%= ph.results.id %>
<% end %>
```

I have an error:

```
undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

What am I doing wrong? I try to get property of Result object that in relation with my Phonecall object.

Comment: Results is a relation. If you want the list of ids you can do ph.result_ids or if you want the Id of the first result you can use ph.results.first.id else you can iterate over it like any other collection / relation

Comment: Do you use rails 3 or rails 4?

Comment: i want to take one id for relation between phonecalls and results

Comment: You can write order more pretty: order(datetime: :desc). And also you need to avoid N+1 query by using include. Finally it'll look like: @phonecalls = Phonecall.include(:results).order(datetime: :desc).to_a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are doing ph.results ***it returns a ActiveRecord Relation and not a single record so you can't call method id on it.*** You need to use some logic to select a single result record from this relation.

If you want to ***display all the ids of results then you'll have to loop through all the results*** and then display them individually like this:

```
- @phonecalls.each do |ph|
  - ph.results.each do |r|
    = r.id
```

Comment: But can i take on record that in relation with current object of Phonecall ? Or i need to do .each cycle and do controll is this record = my current object relation record?

Comment: @user2051503 if you want to display them all then you'll have to loop through all the records present in collection

Comment: nope, i want to display only id of Resultst wich in relation with current Phonecalls object

Comment: That's exactly what Mandeep is doing. Just try it.

Comment: @user2051503 when you do ph.results, it returns a collection of results which belongs to that particular phonecall only. It's a collection of records so you can't just display a single value. You'll either have to loop through all of them or use some logic to select a single result, something like .first or .last but it'll only give first or last record so you'll have to find that logic to select a single record from that collection